# Encoding warning while populating mysql table using python

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I am populating a table in mysql database. There are many lines (say 1 million line). I ran the code successfully and it populates the database with all the rows. But finally I got the following warning (many times) which shows that there is some encoding problem. So I used `charset = 'utf8'` and also used `str.encode('utf8')` for the strings where I thought there is a possibility of such error.

```
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pymysql/cursors.py:167: Warning: (1366, "Incorrect string value: '\\xC5\\xABmo 5...' for column 'productname' at row 1")
  result = self._query(query)
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pymysql/cursors.py:167: Warning: (1366, "Incorrect string value: '\\xE2\\x80\\x90mul...' for column 'productname' at row 1")
  result = self._query(query)
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pymysql/cursors.py:167: Warning: (1366, "Incorrect string value: '\\xE2\\x80\\x90ate...' for column 'productname' at row 1")
  result = self._query(query)
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pymysql/cursors.py:167: Warning: (1366, "Incorrect string value: '\\xE2\\x80\\x90rah...' for column 'productname' at row 1")
  result = self._query(query)
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pymysql/cursors.py:167: Warning: (1366, "Incorrect string value: '\\xE2\\x80\\x90num...' for column 'productname' at row 1")
  result = self._query(query)
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pymysql/cursors.py:167: Warning: (1366, "Incorrect string value: '\\xE2\\x80\\x90puk...' for column 'productname' at row 1")
  result = self._query(query)
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pymysql/cursors.py:167: Warning: (1366, "Incorrect string value: '\\xE2\\x80\\x90lom...' for column 'productname' at row 1")
  result = self._query(query)
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pymysql/cursors.py:167: Warning: (1366, "Incorrect string value: '\\xE2\\x80\\x90ruu...' for column 'productname' at row 1")
  result = self._query(query)
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pymysql/cursors.py:167: Warning: (1366, "Incorrect string value: '\\xE2\\x80\\x90poi...' for column 'productname' at row 1")
  result = self._query(query)
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pymysql/cursors.py:167: Warning: (1366, "Incorrect string value: '\\xE2\\x80\\x90WC-...' for column 'productname' at row 1")
  result = self._query(query)
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pymysql/cursors.py:167: Warning: (1366, "Incorrect string value: '\\xE2\\x80\\x90ham...' for column 'productname' at row 1")
  result = self._query(query)
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pymysql/cursors.py:167: Warning: (1366, "Incorrect string value: '\\xC5\\xABmo 5...' for column 'productname' at row 1")
  result = self._query(query)
```

The code file is big enough but I can put my code which is related to the above issue:

```
try: data = (productid_i, time_i,  store_i,  name_i, price_i,  category_i, url_i, year_i, week_i)
except ValueError as e: print(e)
try: self.cursor.execute('INSERT INTO productinfo (productid, scrappingdate, storeid, productname, price, categoryid, url, annual, week )' 'VALUES("%s", date(%s), "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s" )', data)
except ValueError as e: print(e)
```

Because there are so many lines I cannot check where it effected my string. Can somebody guide me whether this warning really impacts the string and what is the way to overcome this problem ? Thanks

Comment: Where is the code ?

Comment: surely you could spot check the database -- or even write a program that verifies the data...? (I'm guessing there's a high probability of mojibake in the productname column).